# Types of collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeof

I have an array holding misc. content, and I need to somehow produce a new array that will hold types of data at coresponding index, i've tried using:

```
typeof ( ["my", "misc", new Data] ),
```

but it gives me not what I'm expecting... 
Is there a way to generate such array?

Comment: Have a look at my answer, I think this is what you might be looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.

```
var types = ["my", "misc", new Data].map(function (item) {
    return typeof item;
});
```

However, I think this might be what you're looking for:

```
var types = ["my", "misc", new Data].map(function (item) {
    var name = item.constructor && item.constructor.name;
    return name? name: typeof item;
});
```

*Please note that `Function.name` is not standard and depending on the way you declared your functions, there might not be any reliable way to find the function's name.*

Comment: thats pretty close, have a look at the type checking fn, maybe you can improve it somehow.

Comment: ...would be great if it could assert the 'special' case objs.

Comment: like maybe on 'object' result running the ctor.name scan? will it do any better like that?

Comment: @NikolaVukovic What do you mean by special case objects? If you always use named functions as constructor functions you should be able to resolve the object's constructor's name.

Comment: ah, ok, thats a plus.

Comment: @NikolaVukovic I could help you better if you could tell me what's wrong with the result produced by the code I suggested.

Comment: ... nothing's wrong with it, its actually very good one, and you already helped me, I completely forgot the fn.name thing...

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because `typeof` doesn't work in an array context, it will just return the type of your array, which is `object`.

The cross-browser solution is to build a new array with the type of each corresponding element of your original array:

```
var arr = ["my", "misc", new Data()];

var types = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    types.push(typeof(arr[i]));
}
```

Alternatively, you may use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to accomplish the same using a one-liner :)

Comment: ... or you may shim `Array.prototype.map` and use convenient tools instead ;-)

Comment: @zerkms Yes, you may :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function type( o ) {
    var out = typeof o;
    (
     (
      out =
        ( o && o.constructor === window.constructor ) && 'window'
        || ( ( Object.prototype.toString.call( o ) ).match( /\b(\w+)\]$/ ) )[1].toLowerCase()
     ) === 'number'
    )
    && ( isNaN( o ) && ( out = 'NaN' ) );
    return out;
}
```